# Which game platform has the most users?

Tags: platform

If I make a game, what is the best target platform for the most users?

If I don't have an iphone/ipad or android phone, am I not able to make iphone/android game?

I am looking for a platform which I can easily distribute the game for public trial/demo.

Comment: That's actually a wrong question. Don't ask "what platform has the most users". Ask "what platform has the most users *that play games like the one I'm making*"?

Answer (score 9):

> Game platform which have most users

That would probably be Web in general.

> If I don't have an iphone/ipad or android phone, am I not able to make iphone/android game?

Consider using HTML5. That would simplify deployment. However you might still want to have a device(s) to test.

> I am looking for a platform which I can easily distribute the game for public trial/demo.

HTML5 based game would fit this requirement.

Comment: What is that wrong with my answer that is worth down-voting?

Comment: I think this is actually a very good answer. Web-Games will reach all PCs *and* mobile devices alike.

Answer (score 5):

Those are a couple different questions you're asking here.

The single target platform with the *most* users is the PC. Even counting just gamers, the biggest MMO *alone* (Happy Farm) had more than 200 million players at its peak. Compare that to some 70 million sold iPhones (all models, as of end of 2010), 190 million sold Android devices (as of end of October 2011), XBox 360 (55 million units sold), Wii (almost 90 million units sold) or PS3 (50 million units sold) - and only a portion of iPhones and Android devices are used for gaming.

The platform which is the best for *you* to get the most users depends heavily on what style of game you want to do - and on your marketing budget.

Comment: +1 Re the relationship between game genre/style and target market.

Comment: Also consider not just number of users... but competition and market saturation. Odds are if you make a game on iOS, it'll be buried in a sea.... if you make something in WP7, there will be fewer users, but more of a chance to be seen by those users.

Answer (score 3):

Home computers.

Nearly everyone has one, and you can release the game incrementally for free. You also have a much bigger choice on tools, and there are practically no restrictions.

---

> If I don't have an iphone/ipad or android phone, am I not able to make iphone/android game?

You can, but I wouldn't. I believe there are emulators, but it wouldn't give you the feel of the actual system.

Comment: That's a very old school term, _home computers_. I'm surprised you didn't say _microcomputers_. Good old days. I assume you mean PC :)

Comment: @NickWiggill I made the distinction to illustrate that developing for *work* or *mainframe* computers is a very bad idea. Falken did it, and look at all the trouble it caused!

Answer (score 2):

I think mobile is larger than PCs, but they are not all smartphones. But smartphones are quicky gaining speed on PCs.  [Smartphone Shipments Surpass PCs for First Time](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2379665,00.asp).  Though you can probably satisfy everyone (old browser users) with creating games using HTML5.